# How to use callback to chain animations with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, callback, chain

I would like to chain three animations with JavaScript and [Transit.js](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-js). The second one must be launched after the first is complete. For this I'm trying to use callbacks.

It's important for me to separate these three functions. I don't want to nest them.

```
// fn 1

function one(callback) {
  $(body).transition({
      'opacity': '1'
  }, 500, function(){
    callback;
   console.log('callback one');
  });
}    

// fn 2

function two(callback) {
 $('section').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, function(){
   console.log('callback two');
   callback;
  });
}

// fn 3

function three(callback) {
 $('aside').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, function(){
   console.log('callback three');
   callback;
  });
}
```

I start functions like this:

```
one(two(tree()));
```

The problem is, the second function starts before the first is completed. What is wrong with this script?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for it

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your callback function in `setTimeout` function

```js
function one(callback) {
  $(body).transition({
      'opacity': '1'
  }, 500, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      callback();
     console.log('callback one');
   },0);
    
  });
}    

// fn 2

function two(callback) {
 $('section').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      callback();
     console.log('callback two');
   },0);
  });
}

// fn 3

function three(callback) {
 $('aside').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      callback();
     console.log('callback three');
   },0);
  });
}
```

Comment: Because,  running any function in 'setTimeout ' will be called in new context and it will be called after executing the current stack.(It's kind of asynchronous call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reference of the function as the argument instead of passing the executed result.

```
// this would execute the  function `three` and pass the 
// returned value as the argumnet to function `two` 
// after executing `two` the returned value would pass to 
// function function `one` . Since any none of the function is
// returning anything the argument value would be `undefined`
one(two(tree()));
```

---

The better way to make it cyclic is adding the callback as the function reference.

```
function one() {
  $(body).transition({
      'opacity': '1'
  }, 500, two);
}    

// fn 2

function two() {
 $('section').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, three);
}

// fn 3

function three() {
 $('aside').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  // if you don't want to make it cyclic then remove the
  // callback argument `one`
  }, 500, one);
}
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you wanna pass it as an argument then pass the reference as a callback function and within the callback call the function you want.

```
function one(callback) {
  $(body).transition({
      'opacity': '1'
  }, 500, function(){  calback() });
  // or simply
  // }, 500, calback);
}    

// fn 2

function two(callback) {
 $('section').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, , function(){ calback() });
}

// fn 3

function three(callback) {
 $('aside').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, , function(){ calback() });
}


// use nested callbacks as you want
one(function(){ two(function(){ three(function(){}); }); })
```

Comment: it's working but I would like to not have to write inside funcitions. The start and order must be independant and easily amended.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work as you expected.

// fn 3

```
function three() {
 $('aside').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, function(){
   console.log('callback three');

  });
}
```

// fn 2

```
function two() {
 $('section').transition({
  'opacity':'1',
  }, 500, three);
}
```

// fn 1

```
function one() {
  $(body).transition({
      'opacity': '1'
  }, 500, two);
}
one();//invoke fn1
```

Comment: it's working but I would like to not have to write inside funcitions. The start and order must be independant and easily amended.